# How to chain proxy after Tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

How can I use a proxy after Tor? Few sites that I use refuse connections from Tor due to abuse, and because of DDOS many sites behind cloudfare/akamai constantly ask me to do captcha every refresh. So is there a way to do this me -> Tor exit node -> my_proxy -> www ???

Comment: What type of proxy are you trying to use?

Answer (score 6):

There are, probably thousands of combinations you might implement.

I'm trying to collect best Unix-like versions, if somebody know better, easiest, shortest way to setup proxy after Tor, you are welcome to complete my answer.

---

1) Read this article [TransparentProxy](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TransparentProxy) and this [IsolatingProxy](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO/IsolatingProxy), thereafter, you may start anything under [transparently anonymized specific user](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TransparentProxy#Transparentlyanonymizingtrafficforaspecificuser). For example, start Firefox, go to settings -> connection settings, set your proxy for Firefox. Your Firefox will achieve target host by next chain:

```
localhost -> Transparent Port ( Tor ) -> Guard ( Tor ) -> Middle ( Tor ) -> 
-> Exit ( Tor ) -> Your Proxy -> Target Host
```

---

2) Another perfect tool is [proxychains](http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/).

> Dedicated OS: Linux and other Unices.

Configuration file /etc/proxychains.conf should be like:

```
strict_chain
#
# Strict - Each connection will be done via chained proxies
# all proxies chained in the order as they appear in the list
# all proxies must be online to play in chain
# otherwise EINTR is returned to the app

# Make sense only if random_chain
chain_len = 2

# Proxy DNS requests - no leak for DNS data
proxy_dns 

[ProxyList]
# add proxy here ...
socks5         127.0.0.1 9050       # Tor socks5 
socks5         184.152.92.156:37071 # https://hidemyass.com/proxy-list/
```

Now you can launch any browser via proxychains:

```
$ proxychains firefox
```