# What is the best way to hide Tor usage?

Tags: anonymity, proxy-leaks, pre-tor-proxy

I'm looking for the best way to hide Tor usage. Because Tor is banned where I want to use it.

What is the best way to hide Tor?

I've found this web-proxy:

- http://cameleo.ru - looks like it support JavaScript. The best one godsend by the long period.
- I know about socks5 proxy and proxychain. Is it still the best way?
- What about VPN after Tor ? Is it as bad as torrent ?

Comment: Which side do you want to hide Tor from? The server you're connecting to or your ISP?

Comment: From OP's examples, it's clear that they want to use a proxy to hide the Tor exit from the website. See https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1232/me-tor-vpn-how/1235#1235.

Answer (score 6):

I assume you would like to hide the Tor usage from your ISP and/or people in charge of internet censorship where you live and use internet. If thats the case you have some options.

Option 1.

You may use bridges, they will hide your Tor usage to some extend. However, if authorities really focus on you they eventually will find out you are using Tor.

Option 2.

You may use pluggable transport, Depending on your circumstances it may hide your Tor usage even better than first option.

Option 3.

If VPN is allowd in your circumstance, you may connect to VPN and from there you can connect to Tor via Guards or bridges and or pluggable transport.

Option 4.

You may connect to a proxy and from there to connect to Tor Guards, or bridges or pluggable transport.

Option 5.

You may make any combination of option 3 and 4 with multiple VPNs and/or proxies, from there connect to Tor guards, or bridges, or pluggable transport.

You have not provided the details of your situation, but since you yourself are best aware of your own situation you may take the best option form above choices or provide the details of your situation for further analysis.

Finally, be advised, that there is no full proof, long term and credible way to hide Tor usage at this point in time. All methods are temporary in nature, and if any credible investigation arises regarding this matter, your ISP and bunch of other people would know that you were using Tor.

Answer (score 2):

[Bridges](https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges) and Pluggable transports are pretty much made for this. [There are many to choose from](https://www.torproject.org/docs/pluggable-transports.html.en).

A very recent one called `meek` makes it look like you connect to Google or Amazon and in fact you connect to their servers, however you actually end up on a Google App Engine or Amazon EC2 server operated by the Tor project. More information about this specific transport can be found on a [recent article on the Tor Blog](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/how-use-%E2%80%9Cmeek%E2%80%9D-pluggable-transport).

This way you hide the fact **you** are using Tor, not the fact that there is a connection from the Tor network to a given web service.

If you want to hide the fact you are using Tor from the target web service you can for example go through a VPN. To make it also hard for someone with a lot of observation possibilities you might want to use something like a hidden service entrance for the VPN. However then the target is likely to know that you are connecting through a VPN. You might also rent a server somewhere to build this yourself. However, don't forget that this server is likely to be linked with you and depending on how good of a look someone takes at this they might still find out it's you.

Comment: If OP looks at https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Trade#Cloud_Providers_and_Services they'll find providers who accept Bitcoins. By using Bitcoins well anonymized by mixing via Tor, an email account accessed via Tor, and ssh to the server via Tor, the server will be hard to link.

Answer (score 1):

Get a server in a country where Tor is legal. Google Cloud, Amazon EC2, Linode and others are suitable. Install GNU/Linux (e.g. Debian), Tor and [obfs4proxy](https://github.com/Yawning/obfs4), or some other pluggable transport. Use the server as a private bridge with the obfourscator enabled and your traffic will just appear as truly random bytes. Finally, automate all of this and change the server and/or provider each hour/day/month.