# I need to access an online chat and they block connections from Tor exit nodes

Tags: exit-relays, tails, blocked-services

I need to access an online chat and they block connections from Tor exit nodes.

The chat is hosted by mibbit.com

I've tried using free online proxies from within Tor (Tails) but that doesn't seem to work. I've tried a number of them.

Comment: Do you need strong anonymity for this? If not, you could use a VPN service instead of Tor. If you do need strong anonymity, you can tunnel a VPN service through Tor, using the socksproxy option in OpenVPN. But you'll need to use VMs. See my answer to http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1232/me-tor-vpn-how/.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am investigating this possibility.

Comment: Just a note: Mibbit doesn't block Tor traffic. If you cannot join the chat, it is due to the specific IRC network that you are trying to connect with.