# How I can access this website?

Tags: help, blocked-services

I need to access the login page of this website: www.mercadolivre.com.br

This is the login page: https://www.mercadolivre.com/jms/mlb/lgz/login?go=http://www.mercadolivre.com.br/gz/home/logged?display=page

Is it possible to login to this website?

Comment: Do you want to access it over Tor? Are you usign the Tor Browser Bundle? Do you have an account at this site?

Comment: Hello, I use Stable Tor Browser, I have account in this website but I need use Tor for access others accounts. I need download Experimental Tor Browser or Stable ??

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Can you login to this site using your account? What other accounts to you want to use? Are they registered already?

Comment: Yes, I have account, but when I click in My Account ( Entrar ) the website don't enter, if enter in www.mercadolivre.com.br and click in " Entre " in top of page, don't load page ... I really don't know what I can make for load this website. Is like Ebay, is impossible access Ebay ?

Comment: I received this message: " For safety, we block your request " Is impossible access this website with Tor or is possible with other method ??

Comment: The login page is on mercadolivre.com not **.com.br** It seems that this login server blocks connections from Tor exit nodes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use another proxy after Tor, which is not blocked by the service.

[Me -> Tor -> Vpn [How?]](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1232/me-tor-vpn-how)