# Website blocking Tor Traffic

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, censorship, blocked-services

I am trying to access a website with Tor and recently it began rejecting my traffic with "Gateway GEO - IP Alert    This request is blocked by the SonicWall Gateway GEO IP service."  I looked around and it seems this website has blocked all Tor traffic.  How can I get around this?  Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Some websites tend to block IP addresses of Tor exit nodes because the abuse they get from some users anonymously accessing the site using the Tor network. When the website takes such decision, there is no way to circumvent it, as long as they keep their list of Tor exit nodes updated (which they usually do).

If the website in question allow users to make accounts or pseudonyms, you may want to ask them to unban Tor access from your account only. Wikipedia follows this approach, i.e. banning Tor visitors from editing the wiki, but allowing few users to edit the wiki while using Tor as long as they abide by Wikipedia rules and etiquette.

Answer (score 2):

One way to circumvent the blockage is to send the output of Tor network to a VPN or Web proxy as shown blow:

Client---Tor---VPN---Destination site

or

Client---Tor---Web proxy---Destination site

To show more detail it would look like this:

Client---Guard---middle node---exit node---VPN---Destination site

or

Client---Guard---middle node---exit node---Web proxy---Destination site

To figure out how to do this, look at this Q&A:

[Me -> Tor -> Vpn [How?]](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1232/me-tor-vpn-how)