# Help with a website

Tags: blocked-services

Hi I have have been trying to reach this site gamefly.com but they seem to be blocking the content from outside the US in my country but using tor when i try reach there site i get this error message "Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://www.gamefly.com/" on this server. Reference #18.864f655f.1452696659.9fa841f" tried selecting the option My ISP blocks connection and obfs3 bridge but still no go. Any help would be greatful thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **Meek** pluggable transport, and if it won't help, post your error log and `torrc` here, so I'll be able to assist you further

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the site you're trying to visit is blocking connections either from:

- your Tor exit node, because the address is outside of the US, or
- Tor traffic in general.

(Rather than it being your ISP blocking access to the Tor network.)

The solutions are either:

- [Use an exit node](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#ChooseEntryExit) inside the US (see [here](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/733/can-i-exit-from-a-specific-country-or-node?lq=1) for an example), or
- [Use a VPN or proxy](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6109/website-blocking-tor-traffic) instead of (or in conjunction with) Tor.