# What does this message mean? You don't have permission to access /forum/How_do_you_chain_a_proxy_after_TOR___63__/ on this server.?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Clicking the following link: https://tails.boum.org/forum/How_do_you_chain_a_proxy_after_TOR___63__/ on this question: [TAILS os: configuring proxychains for tor > socks5 proxy](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4062/tails-os-configuring-proxychains-for-tor-socks5-proxy) resulted in this message:

403 Forbidden

***Forbidden***

You don't have permission to access /forum/How_do_you_chain_a_proxy_after_TOR___63__/ on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Server at tails.boum.org Port 443

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the forum running on Tails.boum.org has been [closed](https://tails.boum.org/news/report_2013_06/index.en.html). However I found the link content from the Git repo [here](https://git-tails.immerda.ch/tails/plain/wiki/src/forum/How_do_you_chain_a_proxy_after_TOR___63__.mdwn?h=bugfix/browser-resizing).