# How to run the tor browser through a second proxy after Tor?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, proxy, blocked-services

My arch-nemesis, Akamai, is interfering with my ability to live my daily life.

I'd like to use Tor Browser to connect to a website that blocks Tor IP addresses by using an open proxy after Tor.  It doesn't matter which protocol to me, so if the method only works with one protocol, that's fine.

[This question](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1229/how-to-chain-proxy-after-tor/) is very similar, but it doesn't specify browser, and Firefox has too wide of a fingerprinting surface for my application.  I'd like to use Tor Browser's fingerprint from a different IP address.

I have tried the following:

- `cd Browser; torsocks ./firefox --safe-mode` would work in theory if you changed the proxy settings, but in practice, it never actually launches.
- Web-based proxies are right out.  I need an SSL handshake with the remote host to even consider conducting business over the network.
- `cd Browser; proxychains ./firefox --safe-mode` is liable to leak DNS information, isn't it?  I recall reading that `proxychains` doesn't use remote DNS resolution, and just runs a regular `dig` command.

Any suggestions?  If there's something like `proxychains` that runs as its own proxy server and I can just set the proxy to that in `--safe-mode` that might just solve the problem, but for the life of me, I can't find that.

Comment: You said what you tried but you didn't say what is your ultimate goal. Please rephrase your question in a way which shows what root problem you want to solve. Additionally it is not clear what is "question #1229" you are referring to.

Comment: @lulofiv Please visit our [contact link](https://tor.stackexchange.com/contact) to request your account be merged with this one. There's a form for account merges. This will allow you to edit the post directly.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've figured it out.

In `about:config`, change the following settings.

- `network.proxy.socks_remote_dns` -> `false`
- `network.proxy.type` -> `0`
- `extensions.torlauncher.start_tor` -> `false`

Then in `about:addons` disable TorLauncher.

In your `proxychains.conf`, add your proxy after the Tor daemon (9050, rather than the browser's 9150).  Make sure proxy_dns is in the config file.

Run `proxychains (your-tbb-dir)/Browser/firefox`.

The result should be a browser with the fingerprint of the TBB, but an IP address of a different reputation.

When you are done using the restricted site, reset the following settings

- `network.proxy.socks_remote_dns` -> `true`
- `network.proxy.type` -> `1`
- `extensions.torlauncher.start_tor` -> `true`

and re-enable TorLauncher.

I still need to look into a few security aspects of this.  I recall reading that `proxychains` doesn't proxy DNS requests and yet it seems to clearly present an option to do so.

A quick search didn't really get me anywhere, so there's a lot of investigation that I still need to do on this, but I think by using `iptables`, I should be able to ascertain that the browser cannot create requests to anything but Tor.

I hope this helps anyone with the same problem.